# C# threading problem

Tags: c#, multithreading

i have main thread (MainThread) on which I create new thred (lets call it NewThread). In NewThread I call a method that want to invoke some method for MainThread.

The problem is that when I call NewThread.Join() from MainThread, Invoke method from NewThread cant be accomplished/terminate (and whole application freeze for ever...) because MainThread is waiting for NewThread to terminate...

sth like vicious circle... Any ideas how to solve it? I need to have possibility to terminate/abort NewThread from MainThread and be shure NewThread no longer exist.

I hope I was specific enough.

Main thread:

```
void method()
    {
        if(currentthread!=null)
        {
            currentthread.Join();
            currentthread=null;
        }

        sth...

        Backgroundworker worker = new Backgroundworker();
        worker.DoWork += delegate (...)
            {
                currentthread=Thread.CurrentThread;
                Func();
            }
            ....
}
```

NewThread:

```
delegate void FuncDel();
void Func()
{

    if(MainThread.InvokeRequired)
{
    FuncDel funcD = new FuncDel();
    MainThread.InvokeRequired(funcD);
          return;
} 
 ....
}
```

Comment: Will you post your code?

Comment: What technique did you use to invoke your method on MainThread? Was it some kind of Control.Invoke or a like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the obvious answer is that your main thread should never Join() your worker thread if there's a chance the worker thread is going to try to Invoke() something on the main thread.

If you are only using Join() to wait for a shutdown on the main thread, you should first do something like a Thread.Abort(), or better yet, use a thread synchronization object like a Mutex or a shared variable, to indicate to the worker thread that it needs to abort. Once you have signaled the worker thread to abort, **then** allow your main thread to Join() it; your worker thread should always check to see if it has been aborted before trying to Invoke a method on the main thread.

If you're using Join() for some other reason, you should again look into the thread synchronization objects like a Mutex. These allow your threads to wait for each other to send them signals -- your worker thread could "wake up" your main thread  before it needs to Invoke(), to ensure your main thread is getting CPU time to do it's work.

Comment: +1: Though I tend to prefer an `EventWaitHandle` in that kind of situation over a `Mutex`.

Answer (score 0):

That's what Thread.Join does, it blocks your calling thread until the Joined thread terminates.  I guess I don't know why you're using join if you simply want to Invoke on another thread. As was stated before, code would help clarify the situation.

You can poll ThreadState in order to check the state of your threads vs using a Join if your implementation won't allow for you to block your main thread.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you almost want the cancellation pattern. Try this TPL option:

```
 CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
         if(cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            return;

         // Do Stuff
    });
```

You can basically fire off a task for the operation you want to do, and if you need to cancel it, you can simply call

```
 cts.Cancel();
```

Your example is pretty convoluted; having a thread spun off to invoke some method has nothing to do with the original thread.

Comment: unfortunatelly TPL works with .net 4.0 - while I use previous version.